# add a fixed number as a column to a matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix

if

```
A=[1 2 3;
2 3 4;
5 6 7;
3 4 5]
```

How can I using Matlab add a fixed number for example 10 to A as a column to have:

```
A=[1 2 3 10;
2 3 4 10;
5 6 7 10;
3 4 5 10]
```

Comment: `B = 10*ones(size(A,1),1), A1 = [A B];`

Comment: `A(:,end+1)=10`

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments already, an easy and efficient way to do this is:

```
A(:,end+1)=10
```